# Facebook and twitter oAuth redirect URL after login in j2me blackberry 7.1, but onAuthorize() not called

Tags: facebook-graph-api, blackberry, java-me, twitter-oauth

I want to integrate facebook and twitter sharing functionality in my j2me blackberry application. I have added relative jar files and able to login on respective APIs. But in both twitter and facebook, after login redirect URL is called but onAuthorize() method is not invoked and so I am not able to get access token and so not able to post anything on twitter and facebook.

Below is my twitter implementation code:

```
 class ShowAuthBrowser extends MainScreen implements OAuthDialogListener
{
    BrowserField b = new BrowserField();

    public ShowAuthBrowser() 
    {


       UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen();
            }
        });
        //}



        add(b);
        pageWrapper = new BrowserFieldOAuthDialogWrapper(b,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,CALLBACK_URL,this);
        pageWrapper.setOAuthListener(this);

    }

    public void doAuth( String pin )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( pin == null )
            {
                pageWrapper.login();
                //Dialog.alert( "pin is null" );
            }
            else
            {
                this.deleteAll();
                add(b);
                //Dialog.alert( "pin is null else" );
                pageWrapper.login(pin);
            } 

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            final String message = "Error loggin Twitter: " + e.getMessage();
            Dialog.alert( message );

        }           
    }

    public void onAccessDenied(String response ) {


        updateScreenLog( "Acceso denegado! -> " + response );

    }

    public void onAuthorize(final Token token) {


        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Dialog.alert("mytoken::"+token);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen();
            }
        });

        final Token myToken = token;
        storeToekn.set("twitter_token", myToken.getToken());
        storeToekn.commit();


        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                 // sharing code...   
            }
        });

    }

    public void onFail(String arg0, String arg1) {
        updateScreenLog("Error authenticating user! -> " + arg0 + ", " + arg1);
    }
}
```

can someone please help me out for this?

Comment: check this http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/posting-to-facebook-wall.html

Comment: @Signare I have also tried that code, but I am getting classdefnotfounderror exception for Facebook class. I had googling for that but did not find any solution.  Event tried to run sample code named strawBerry application demo for facebook sharing, but getting same classdefnotfounderror error in that app.

Comment: you adding jar file ?

Comment: yes. I have added both jar files. log4b and facebook_api_me-1.0.jar.